# haskell-stack getting TlsExceptionHostPort error

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

Been running stack/ghc inside Debian 8.2 via vagrant for a while. This morning:

```
$  stack setup
Run from outside a project, using implicit global project config
Using resolver: lts-4.2 from implicit global project's config file: /home/vagrant/.stack/global-project/stack.yaml
Downloading lts-4.2 build plan ...TlsExceptionHostPort (HandshakeFailed (Error_Protocol ("certificate has expired",True,CertificateExpired))) "raw.githubusercontent.com" 443

$  stack --version
Version 1.0.2, Git revision fa09a980d8bb3df88b2a9193cd9bf84cc6c419b3 (3084 commits) x86_64
```

The same error remains even if I delete `~/.stack`. Did I mess something up?

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32654493/1651941
You may want to re-open this issue if doesn't help: https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/1668

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try running `stack -v setup` to be able to see which files are being downloaded.
Then identify which file(s) cannot be downloaded due to this `TlsExceptionHostPort` - hopefully there won't be too many of them - and run:

```
curl -0 https://raw.githubusercontent.com/path_to_your_file > your_file
```

Once your blocking file(s) have been downloaded, re-run `stack setup`.

This might not be a clean approach, but it worked for me.